# Unable to update from Ubuntu 20.04 ro 20.10

Tags: do-release-upgrade, release-management

I am trying to update my system from 20.04 to 20.10

If I try through the Update Manager after installing all available updates I am toldI am up to date but that 20.10 is available.  Click on Update and the Update Manager simply closes, no update.

If I try manually via Terminal it also fails.  Tried the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

then

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

and it falls over telling me that I need to
"Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading."

I thought they all were up to date, but it would appear from running `apt-list --upgradable` that libc++1 needs to be updated, but I can't find any obvious way to do that.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check you haven't put any holds on packages (that would prevent upgrade), eg. `apt-mark showhold`

Comment: Show the output of `apt-list --upgradable` . And `apt-cache policy libc++1:amd64 libc++1:i386` .

Answer (score 0):

try synaptic package manager (`sudo apt install synaptic`) and updating from there, it sometimes update packages that cannot be updated through command lines, hope this solves the problem